# Can I set a variable from win powershell, that will last until user logs out?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, environment-variables

I am working on windows powershell script, that suppose to run periodically when user is logged in on the computer. In certain conditions the script should stop being executed - i am using a dummy file as a semaphore to mark that between executions. The problem is that, the script should get back to it's activity after user restarts the computer. Keeping a file as an indicator is troublesome here.

Is there maybe any type of env variable in windows (win10 in particular) that could be shared between processes, but wiuld be reset or removed at system restart?

Comment: You might need to restate the problem. See the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) since it looks like you've decided on a solution that may not be the best way to solve your problem; or may not even be possible to implement.